# Circle Indicator is not visible

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I don't know Why `Circle Indicator` is  not visible in banner layout. I'am using library `"me.relex:circleindicator"`. But it is not working  . I want the circleIndicator below my imageView but it is not visible.

The screenshot shown below shows where I want that circle indicator.

[image]

This my code in mainactivity :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener;
    @BindView(R.id.vp_mainLayout)
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @BindView(R.id.circleindicator)
    CircleIndicator circleIndicator;
    //    private ViewPager viewPager;
    //    private CircleIndicator circleIndicator;
    int gambar[] = {R.drawable.banner1, R.drawable.banner2, 
    R.drawable.no_photo, 
    R.drawable.peta_indonesia};
    private int currentPage = -1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
        ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#300000ff")));
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
        ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getSupportActionBar().setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new 
        ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));

        BannerAdapter bannerAdapter = new BannerAdapter(gambar, 
        MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(bannerAdapter);
        circleIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);


bannerAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(circleIndicator.getDataSetObserver());
```

This My Adapter :

```
public class BannerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

int[] gambar;
Activity activity;

public BannerAdapter(int[] gambar, Activity activity) {
    this.gambar = gambar;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return gambar.length;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_banner, container, false);
    ImageView img = v.findViewById(R.id.imgbanner);

    Glide.with(activity)
            .load(gambar[position])
            .into(img);

    container.addView(v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
}
```

This My XML :

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/circleindicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:ci_gravity="center" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This my Item Banner :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgbanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try viewpager height as wrap_content

Comment: yes i've tried the wrap content before but not work

Comment: have you used background color as white?

Comment: No,  @Jyoti JK... I do not give any color in the background

Comment: try setting ci_drawable for circleIndicator

Comment: Not work too @Jyoti JK,,,

Comment: for me it is showing. for checking purpose set android:background="@color/colorAccent" this to CircleIndicator and see background color is visible or not

Comment: have you set viewpager to your indicator in java using `indicator.setViewPager(viewpager);`?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the CircleIndicator's color is white and because your layout's default color is white. the CircleIndicator isn't visible.

you can use the following attributes in your XML file to make it visible

```
app:ci_drawable="@drawable/white_radius_circle_indicator"
app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/black_radius_circle_indicator"
```

Here the **app:ci_drawable** is used for the selected circle and **app:ci_drawable_unselected** for the unselected circle.

res/drawable/white_radius_circle_indicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid
    android:color="@color/accent"/>
</shape>
```

res/drawable/black_radius_circle_indicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid
    android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just elevate your Circle Page Indicator with:

```
android:translationZ="4dp"
```

At least it is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML to this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="230dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"> 
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
    android:id="@+id/circleindicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:ci_gravity="center" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).